# phpBB3 Display specific Custom Profile Fields for custom UCP module

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I have added a custom module for the User Control Panel called 'Website customisation'

What I'd like is to have certain Custom Profile Fields show up there, but not all of them. Is there a way to limit which fields that show up based on their Field Identification?

I want the rest of the fields to show up on the normal profile page.

Can this be done? :)

```
<!-- BEGIN profile_fields --><!-- IF profile_fields.FIELD_ID eq "secret_society" -->
    <dl>
        <dt><label<!-- IF profile_fields.FIELD_ID --> for="{profile_fields.FIELD_ID}"<!-- ENDIF -->>{profile_fields.LANG_NAME}:<!-- IF profile_fields.S_REQUIRED --> *<!-- ENDIF --></label>
        <!-- IF profile_fields.LANG_EXPLAIN --><br /><span>{profile_fields.LANG_EXPLAIN}</span><!-- ENDIF --></dt>
        <!-- IF profile_fields.ERROR --><dd class="error">{profile_fields.ERROR}</dd><!-- ENDIF -->
        <dd style="margin-top:10px;">{profile_fields.FIELD}</dd>
    </dl>
<!-- ENDIF --><!-- END profile_fields -->
```

Comment: yes it can. What have you tried so far? We need to see some code.

Comment: Added some code to the OP :) What I want to achieve with that code is to only pull the Custom Profile Field that has the Field Identification "secret_society", but that code sample does not work

Comment: try replacing `FIELD_ID` with `PROFILE_FIELD_NAME`. Also, is `profile_fields` running inside another loop?

Comment: PROFILE_FIELD_NAME didn't work, but I found a similar solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more experimentation based on ideas from user Eeji, I discovered a solution:

```
<!-- BEGIN profile_fields --><!-- IF profile_fields.FIELD_ID eq "pf_secret_society" -->
    <dl>
        <dt><label<!-- IF profile_fields.FIELD_ID --> for="{profile_fields.FIELD_ID}"<!-- ENDIF -->>{profile_fields.LANG_NAME}:<!-- IF profile_fields.S_REQUIRED --> *<!-- ENDIF --></label>
        <!-- IF profile_fields.LANG_EXPLAIN --><br /><span>{profile_fields.LANG_EXPLAIN}</span><!-- ENDIF --></dt>
        <!-- IF profile_fields.ERROR --><dd class="error">{profile_fields.ERROR}</dd><!-- ENDIF -->
        <dd style="margin-top:10px;">{profile_fields.FIELD}</dd>
    </dl>
<!-- ENDIF --><!-- END profile_fields -->
```

Apparently, I just needed to prefix the ID with pf_ (profile field) as all profile fields have their ID prefixed with that in the database.